Equivalent functions are both $L_1$
Let $f(x) \sim g(x)$ and $f(x) \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$. Then it is stated that $g(x) \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$, is that true?
I feel like the answer is positive, but I can not bound $g(x)$ from above with something..
Updated: I have this question because of the following topic
I do not understand implication: "if $M\neq 0$ then $|f(x)|\sim |M|$ (in $+\infty$) this is impossible because a constant function $x\to |M|$ is not integrable on $[0,+\infty[$ but $f$ is integrable on this interval".
How did we get that stated equality is impossible? if functions are equivalent, we can not say something about their integrals?

What do you mean by "equivalent"?

@Zima, $f(x) \sim g(x)$ means that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x} = 1$

Under that assumption, definitely not. Take any $L^1$ function for $f$ and let $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\geq 0$ and $g(x)=1$ when $x<0$. This is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. You need stronger constraints on $f$ and $g$.

@JoshB., my question is related to this topic. it seems like this statement about equal functions both in $L_1$ is used there (in Hamou's answer) : $f \in L_1$ and $f \sim M$ but $M$ is not in $L_1$ and somehow he gets contradiction

Can you please modify your original question to reflect what you are trying to ask? Your question has been answered as stated, but the link you provided discusses a different, albeit tangentially similar, problem.

@JoshB., done. I do not understand why $|f(x)| \sim |M|$ is impossible for $|M| \neq 0$. Initially I've created this question to figure this out.

If $M$ is a nonzero constant, ask yourself, what is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty M,dx$? It's not defined, so a constant function is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. If $f\sim M$, then that means that as $x$ gets large $f(x)$ approaches $M$ (assuming $M$ is positive), and so $f$ is at least larger than $M/2$. Thus, by a similar argument, $f$ does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.
